# $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^{k} \Gamma(\frac{2k+n+m}{2})\Gamma(\frac{2k+m-1}{2})}{2^{2k}k!\Gamma(k+\frac{m}{2})} z^{2k}$ is an elementary function

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

I try to calculate the following series
\begin{align*}
S_{n,m}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\, (-1)^{k} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{2k+n+m}{2})\,\Gamma(\frac{2k+m-1}{2})}{2^{2k}k!\,\Gamma(k+\frac{m}{2})} \,  z^{2k}. \qquad \qquad (*)
\end{align*}
where $\Gamma(z)$ is the Gamma function and where $n,m\in \mathbb Z^+$ (non-negative integers).

More precisely I would like to show that the series $(*)$ is an elementary function.

I used the Legendre's duplication formula:
\begin{align*}
\Gamma (z)\;\Gamma \left(z+{\frac {1}{2}}\right)=2^{1-2z}\;{\sqrt {\pi }}\;\Gamma (2z),
\end{align*}
to simplify the expression of the series $(*)$, but without success.

Otherwise, I thought of the hypergeometric functions:
$$\displaystyle {}_{2}F_{1}(a,b;c;z)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(a+n)\Gamma(b+n)}{\Gamma(c+n)}  \frac{z^{n}}{n!}.$$
Then, returning back to $(*)$, keeping in mind the expression of the hypergeometric functions $\displaystyle {}_{2}F_{1}(a,b;c;z)$, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
S_{n,m}(z)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\, (-1)^{k} \frac{\Gamma(k+\frac{n+m}{2})\,\Gamma(k+\frac{m-1}{2})}{k!\,\Gamma(k+\frac{m}{2})} \, \left(\frac{z}{2}\right)^{2k}\\
&= {}_{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{n+m}{2},\frac{m-1}{2};\frac{m}{2};z\right)\\
&= {}_{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{m}{2}+\frac{n}{2},\frac{m}{2}-\frac{1}{2};\frac{m}{2};-(z/2)^2\right)??
\end{align*}
If that's right, how can I show that $S_{n,m}(z)$ is an elementary function?

Thank you in advance

Comment: By a transformation formula $$S_{n,m}(z)=
(1 + (z/2)^2 )^{\frac{{1 - m - n}}{2}} {}_2F_1 \left( { - \tfrac{n}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};\tfrac{m}{2}; - (z/2)^2 } \right).
$$ Thus it is certainly elementary when $n$ is even and non-negative.

Comment: Note: Your definition of $S_{n,m}(z)$ runs into a problem at $m=1$ since then $\Gamma(\frac{2k+m-1}{2})$ will be undefined at $k=0$. Also, this is a nitpick, but $\mathbb Z^+$ typically denotes the positive integers rather than nonnegative integers.

Comment: Ok, I will see, thank you